# Writing assert messages to log file

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, assert

I have written a c++ application to be run on an embedded device running onboard Linux OS. For debug purposes I have inserted std::cout statements in my application.

I run the application using the below command to store all my log messages into a file

```
./TestApplication > /var/log/test_log
```

As expected all the log messages are stored in `test_log`. But when the application faces an assertion, the assert message is not stored in the log file.

My application depends on a lot of third party packages which each have their own custom assert function. Hence writing my own custom assert function for the application as a whole will be too difficult as I need to cater for the third party custom asserts also.

Is there a simple way to dump all my log and assert messages into a log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command redirects stdout to the *test_log* file. Assert message is written to stderr stream. You should instead try:

```
./TestApplication 1>/var/log/test_log 2>/var/log/test_log_errors
```

or

```
./TestApplication 2>&1 > /var/log/test_log
```

if you want to have it all in one file (`2>1&` means "redirect stderr to stdout")

Answer (score 2):

On a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) there are two output streams:

1. Standard output (used by `std::cout` in C++)
2. Standard error (used by `std::cerr` and `std::clog` in C++)

With the plain `>` shell redirection operator, you redirect only standard output, not standard error (where e.g. assert messages are written).

You need to tell the shell that standard error should be the same as standard output, using `2>&1`:

```
./TestApplication > /var/log/test_log 2>&1
```

Note that order of the redirections matter.

Read more about [redirection](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION) in the [Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

---

If you wonder about the numbers in `2>&1`, it's the standard file descriptor numbers. Descriptor `0` is standard input (that you read with `std::cin`); Descriptor `1` is standard output; And descriptor `2` is standard error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. When I try out this command, the error messages are appended to the beginning of the file, and not in the order they occur. Any way we could have the error messages written to the file in the order they occur?

Comment: @rudhan-sacra That shouldn't happen, unless you're doing something "weird". The redirection to the file should write to the file only when something is written to standard output, there's no ordering or sorting of any kind.